# django-import-export how to handle GenericRelations?

Tags: python, django, django-import-export, django-generic-relations

I'm using [django-import-export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html#import_export.widgets.ForeignKeyWidget) module to export the record. However, I couldn't export the generic relations. I just want to get all the details of GenericRelation.

Found the snippet below in Github but it doesn't work.

```
class DudeResource(resources.ModelResource):
    address = fields.Field(
        column_name='address',
        attribute='address',
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Address, 'name'))  # use a unique field

    class Meta:
        model = Dude
        fields = ['address']
```

**My Models**

```
Company
|-- Name
|--- Address(Generic Relation)

Address
|--content_type
|--object_id
|--content_object
|--line_1
|--line_2
|--city
|--country
```

I just need to import/export line_1, line_2, city, and country. Can someone help me on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the fields like this...

class DudeResource(resources.ModelResource):

```
class Meta:
    model = Dude
    fields = ['address__line_1', 'address__line_2', 'address__city',
              'address__line_1', 'address__country', ]
```

Comment: Yes, this didn't work. This only works for related fields.